# IIF function- return specific values based on the month

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, iif-function

I'm trying to write a query that will populate the "Quarter" field with either Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 depending on which month a certain transaction occurred in.  I'm attempting it this way, which I think is rather clunky:

```
IIf([Original Date] like “7*” Or [original date] like “8*” or [original date] like “9*”, “Q1”, IIf ([Original Date] like “10*” or [Original Date] like “11*” or [Original Date] like “12*”, “Q2”, IIF([Original Date] like “1*” or [Original Date] like “2*” or [Original Date] like “3*”, “Q3”, IIf([Original Date] like “4*” or [Original Date] like “5*” or [Original Date] like “6*”, “Q4”, Null))))
```

This doesn't work, however.  I was thinking maybe because the [Original Date] field is a Date/Time data type.  Is there a better way to write this query?

Comment: You can use the month function: https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/month.php. `month[Original Date]=7...`

Comment: I tried this, just to simplify and see if it works:  Reportable Quarter: IIf(Month([Original Date])=6,“Q1”,Null).  That does not work though...

Comment: Weird... have you tried with an `[Original Date]` of June? The `month` function is quite "straightforward", so I cannot understand why don't you get anything

Comment: I think it has to do with data type.  When I changed it to Reportable Quarter: IIf(Month([Original Date])=6,1,Null) it works... Do you know if it's possible to change that to Short Text in the function?  The field in the table it's appending to is set to Short Text.

Comment: You could convert your short text field to date, and then apply the `month` function on the converted field. I would need to know what format is using your short text field to store the dates (yyyy-mm-dd, dd-mm-yyyy, ...?)

Answer (score 1):

Use [DatePart("q")](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datepart-function-26868a79-5505-4e5a-8905-6001372223fa), if `[Original Date]` is a date.

(If not, use `CDate()`)

```
SELECT "Q" & DatePart("q", [Original Date]) AS Quarter
FROM myTable
```

Oh wait, your Q1 starts in July. Then e.g. modify the date, adding 6 months:

```
SELECT "Q" & DatePart("q", DateAdd("m", 6, [Original Date])) AS Quarter
FROM myTable
```